# Delete Mutations not working in Prisma with GraphQL Nexus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, prisma

I'm trying to write a delete mutation and I'm getting some weird behavior. If i go to the frontend of the app and click on the delete button twice then refresh the page, the record gets deleted from the database. But If I click It once, then refresh, It's still there in the database.

This is the error that prints to the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: 
Invalid `context.db.user.delete()` invocation in
/home/eric/DEV/Junk/nexus-prisma-app/api/graphql/User.ts:84:44`
An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. Record to delete does not exist.
```

So in the front end I have to click my delete button twice for it to work, however the same error prints out, and the function doesn't re-fetch the query. If I go into the Apollo sandbox I can delete a record by ID only running the mutation once, but it still prints out the same error indicating it didn't work, but if I go to fetch the users again, the user has been deleted and the mutation worked.

/api/graphql/User.ts:

```
import { extendType, nonNull, objectType, stringArg } from "nexus";

export const User = objectType({
  name: "User",
  definition(t) {
    t.string("id");
    t.string("name");
    t.string("username");
    t.string("email");
  },
});

export const GetUsersQuery = extendType({
  type: "Query",
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.list.field("users", {
      type: "User",
      resolve(_root, _args, context) {
        return context.db.user.findMany();
      },
    });
  },
});

export const UserMutations = extendType({
  type: "Mutation",
  definition(t) {
    t.field("createUser", {
      type: "User",
      args: {
        name: nonNull(stringArg()),
        username: nonNull(stringArg()),
        email: nonNull(stringArg()),
      },
      resolve(_root, args, context) {
        const newUser = {
          name: args.name,
          username: args.username,
          email: args.email,
        };
        return context.db.user.create({ data: newUser });
      },
    });
    t.nonNull.list.field("findUser", {
      type: "User",
      args: {
        email: nonNull(stringArg()),
      },
      resolve(_root, args, context) {
        console.log(args);
        return context.db.user.findMany({
          where: {
            email: args.email,
          },
        });
      },
    });
  },
});

export const DeleteUserMutation = extendType({
  type: "Mutation",
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.list.field("deleteUser", {
      type: "User",
      args: {
        id: nonNull(stringArg()),
      },
      async resolve(_root, args, context) {
        console.log(args.id);
        return await context.db.user.delete({
          where: {
            id: args.id,
          },
        });
      },
    });
  },
});
```

I get this problem in VS Code:

```
Type '(_root: {}, args: { id: string; }, context: Context) => Promise<User>' is not assignable to type 'FieldResolver<"Mutation", "deleteUser">'.
  Type 'Promise<User>' is not assignable to type 'MaybePromise<({ email?: string | null | undefined; id?: string | null | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; username?: string | null | undefined; } | null)[]> | MaybePromise<...>'.
    Type 'Promise<User>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<MaybePromise<{ email?: string | null | undefined; id?: string | null | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; username?: string | null | undefined; } | null>[]>'.
      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
        Type '<TResult1 = User, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: User) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = MaybePromise<{ email?: string | null | undefined; id?: string | null | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; username?: string | null | undefined; } | null>[], TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: MaybePromise<...>[]) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined, onrejected?: (...'.
          Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'MaybePromise<{ email?: string | null | undefined; id?: string | null | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; username?: string | null | undefined; } | null>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing `list` from `t.nonNull.list.field("deleteUser"{/***/}) fixes the problem.

```
export const DeleteUserMutation = extendType({
  type: "Mutation",
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.field("deleteUser", {
      type: "User",
      args: {
        id: nonNull(stringArg()),
      },
      resolve(_root, args, context) {
        return context.db.user.delete({
          where: {
            id: args.id,
          },
        });
      },
    });
  },
});
```